# Showing that $\text{Hom}(M,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}))\simeq \text{Hom}(\widetilde{M},\mathcal{F})$ (exercise II.5.3 from Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

This is exercise II.5.3 from Hartshore:

> Let $X=\text{Spec}(A)$ be an affine scheme. Show that the functors $\widetilde{\,\,\,\,}$ and $\Gamma$ are adjoint, in the following sense: for any $A$-module $M$, and for any sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathcal{F}$, there is a natural isomorphism:
>   $$\text{Hom}_A(M,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}))\simeq\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\widetilde{M},\mathcal{F})$$

Since $\widetilde{M}(X)=M$, $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{F}(X)$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(X)=A$, then given a morphism $\psi:\widetilde{M}\to\mathcal{F}$, we have that $\psi_X:M\to\mathcal{F}(X)$ is an $A$-module morphism, therefore in $\text{Hom}_A(M,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}))$.

Conversely, if $\phi:M\to\mathcal{F}(X)$, I think the natural idea is to define $\phi_f:M_f\to\mathcal{F}(X)_f$ for each $f\in A$, which can be glued to obtain a morphism $\psi:\widetilde{M}\to\widetilde{\mathcal{F}(X)}$.

But is it true that $\widetilde{\mathcal{F}(X)}=\mathcal{F}$? I tried to show that $\mathcal{F}(X_f)=\mathcal{F}(X)_f$, but I don't know how to do it only knowing that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true in general that $\widetilde{\mathcal F(X)}=\mathcal F$; there exist $\mathcal O_X$-modules which are not of the form $\widetilde M$ for any $M$.

However, what we do know is that there is a restriction map $\mathcal F(X)\to\mathcal F(X_f)$ for any $f\in A$. But $\mathcal F(X_f)$ is a module over $\mathcal O_X(X_f)=A_f$, so multiplication by $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal F(X_f)$, so by the universal property of localization of modules there is an induced ($A_f$-module) morphism $\mathcal F(X)_f\to\mathcal F(X_f)$ (making the corresponding triangle commute).

Combining with the map $M_f\to \mathcal F(X)_f$ you found, we get a map $\widetilde M(X_f)=M_f\to\mathcal F(X_f)$, and these you can glue to get a sheaf morphism $\widetilde M\to\mathcal F$.